# Low-rep bounty-setters should be able to comment on answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, bounty, privileges

Someone with insufficient reputation to comment should nonetheless be able to comment on answers to a (not closed) question he set a bounty on. This would allow him to seek clarification of answers.

Comment: I think askers can comment on answers.

Comment: ...This should already be possible? Comment everywhere is 50 rep, set bounties is 75 rep. [See the privileges page](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges) for more information.

Comment: @Aarthi What if I have 75 and then start a 50 point bounty on someone else's question: don't I lose my comment privilege on that question?

Comment: Oh, dang, you're right. I didn't think of that scenario. On the other hand: there are much higher rep users around the site who'd be happy to make a bounty for you? I dunno; I think making a bounty can be communal, too.

Comment: @Aarthi I imagine it isn't too hard to extend commenting privileges to the bounty owner independent of rep, just like he can comment on his own questions independent of rep.

Comment: @Aarthi, or he sets a bounty and then posts a really unpopular answer somewhere else on the site...

Comment: @Aarthi http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/440?m=6082253#6082253

Comment: Yes, per [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757), @DoubleAA is correct that askers can comment on their answers. I'll edit this question to be about bounty-setters only, not askers.